# Install ttf file in android without using any font installers

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to create a program that can install google fonts in android device. Using

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v11/mE5BOuZKGln_Ex0uYKpIaw.ttf");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

i am able to download the font mentioned in url in my android device but when i try to open it, it says unrecognized file type. Previously i had installed Hifont. using HiFont i could open my file but is there any way to open these kind of file without using hifont or any type of installer? Please Help me...